# Create interface list with class type, then cast to type returns null

Tags: c#, casting

Trying to make a generic load file to list function in a simple parser project.
It will return a list as long I use IList< interface > but when trying to cast to the actual List< class > it returns null.

```
public async static Task<IList<IFileHandlerLineVO>> LoadLineByLine(string path, Type toClass)
{
    if (!FileExist(path))
        return null;

    List<IFileHandlerLineVO> list = new List<IFileHandlerLineVO>();

    StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(path);
    string readline;
    while ((readline = await fs.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
    {
        IFileHandlerLineVO instance = (IFileHandlerLineVO)Activator.CreateInstance(toClass);
        instance.Input = readline;
        list.Add(instance);

        // NOTE: A cast here shows that instance is the correct class 'GameSortVO'
    }

    fs.Close();
    fs.Dispose();

    return list;
}
```

The Class (ValueObject) with interface

```
public class GameSortVO : IFileHandlerLineVO
{
    public string Input { get; set; }
    public string Output { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int Random { get; set; }
}
```

So this is how I use it. **This works**

```
IList<IFileHandlerLineVO> list = await FileHandler.LoadLineByLine(game.Filepath, typeof(GameSortVO)) as IList<IFileHandlerLineVO>;
```

However, I want to run this. **Does not work** any suggestions?

```
IList<GameSortVO> list = await FileHandler.LoadLineByLine(game.Filepath, typeof(GameSortVO)) as IList<GameSortVO>;

breakpoint shows
    list    null    System.Collections.Generic.IList<parser.vo.GameSortVO>
```

Comment: It doesn't work because an `IList<IFileHandlerLineVO>` is not an `IList<GameSortVO>`. so you can't cast them

Comment: That's because the *calling* code doesn't have any guarantee that *every* `IFileHandlerLineVO` that's been inserted into the list that `LoadLineByLine` returns is in fact a `GameSortVO`, just based on that method's signature. Either work with just the interfaces and don't write that calling code or change the signature of the method so that the concrete type you want is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast elements, not the list itself.
You can use Linq's Cast method to cast elements:

```
var list = await LoadLineByLine("aaa", typeof(GameSortVO));
var listGameSortVO = list.Cast<GameSortVO>();
```

Comment: This didn't help me getting List<GameSortVO> but can try using Linq for all my needs instead.